# MS Access tables with name beginning with "{"

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

My MS Access query

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Type, MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=1) AND ((MSysObjects.Name) Like "{*"));
```

is showing >3,000 local tables whose names begin with "{".  I didn't knowingly create these.

E.g.

```
Type    Name
1   {00191663-6977-4C13-A56F-0E0A36697A81}
1   {00191663-6977-4C13-A56F-0E0A36697A81}_shadow
1   {001E812C-A324-40AF-B3F8-9703969260B5}
1   {001E812C-A324-40AF-B3F8-9703969260B5}_shadow
```

My database is surprisingly large.  I tried doing a compact/repair and these remain.

I am linking to a number of SharePoint lists.  Are these tables needed by SharePoint?  Or, can I safely delete these?

I'm using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Access, Access version 16.0.11929.20978.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are SharePoint list IDs.

`{00191663-6977-4C13-A56F-0E0A36697A81}` is called a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). SharePoint uses GUIDs to identify lists (while a name is shown, what's actually used is a GUID).

I would not recommend deleting these. If size becomes a problem, note that there are multiple ways you can cache SharePoint tables, and some cache a large amount of data. You can toggle this per database, under Options -> Current database:

[image]

Comment: This is helpful.  I did a select on some of these tables and they were indeed from the SharePoint lists that I linked to.  However, I then deleted the links to all linked tables and did a ```Compact & Repair```.  The GUID files and the excessive size remains.  I'm thinking that I need to recreate the db.

Comment: @mherzog Have you checked "Clear cache on close" in the options? One tricky thing that can happen is that pre-2010 caches and post-2010 caches can get mixed up (I actually did this on purpose in one project since the pre-2010 ones have some more options) and then Access can get confused. Clearing the SharePoint cache is separate from compact & repair

Comment: Playing with the Caching settings in the Options screen above reduced the number of GUID files from about 3,200 to 1,776.  The number of these GUID files and the db size is still much larger than a fresh db with the same linked tables.